# Why is there an incongruence between dataframe input and numeric standard input?

Tags: python, pandas, geocode

```
nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('nl')
nomi.query_postal_code("1081")

Out:postal_code                1081
    country_code                 NL
    place_name            Amsterdam
    state_name        Noord-Holland
    state_code                    7
    county_name           Amsterdam
    county_code                 363
    community_name              NaN
    community_code              NaN
    latitude                52.3278
    longitude                 4.862
    accuracy                      6
    Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I have the following df column:

```
     Postalcodestring
0    41460
1     7411
2      NaN
Name: Postalcodestring, dtype: object
```

When I input

```
df['City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code(1081)['place_name']
 
     City1
0    Amsterdam
1    Amsterdam
2    Amsterdam
```

However, when I input the following code to adapt to the df column:

```
df['City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code('Postalcodestring')['place_name']
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
Name: City1, dtype: float64
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Hi Max, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may help you.

Modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pgeocode
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Postalcodestring':[41460, 7411, np.nan]}, dtype='int32')
```

Note that the first postcode returns a NAN (41460 does not exist in the Netherlands), and the third has as input a NAN so should also return a NAN.

The following returns [NAN, "Deventer", NAN]

```
df['City1'] = df['Postalcodestring'].apply(lambda x: nomi.query_postal_code(int(x))['place_name'] if(pd.notnull(x)) else x)
```

Comment: Thank you Ruthger, this helped a ton! Have a good day man.